# How to solve compiling error?

Tags: pdftex

I am getting a problem when compiling my dissertation.

I want to know in which line the mistake occurs?

How can I do that?

Comment: the log file has an error message with a line starting like `l.123` if the tex error is detected on line 123

Answer (score 4):

See for example the following MWE with an error:

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315916/how-to-solve-compiling-error
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello \World!
\end{document}
```

After compiling this you get an `log` file containing the following lines:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 Hello \World                   <========================================= error here===
                !
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

{C:/Users/Internet/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (315916-HelloWorld.aux) )
```

There line `! Undefined control sequence.` is the error message.

The line `l.4 Hello \World` mentions that in the line 4 of the given code the error has been **recognised**!

Please see that the error could happen earlier, but in this simple example the error was correct found.

Line `!` shows that sign `!` was not part of the error.

Then follows the error description, telling you that `\World` (the last showed control sequence) is not defined.

That is true, because for the `HelloWorld` example we do not need an command here, so the leading `\` is just a typo.  If there should be an command `\World` it has to be defined like `\newcommand{\World}{World}` or ...

The end of the error description is line `and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

The resulting pdf of the MWE with error is

[image]

showing that `Hello` and `!` are printed, but `World` is of course missing.  That could be another hint to find the error without knowing the complete meaning of the given error message ...

BTW: the line `[1` in the `log` file shows that page 1 has been started to be print ...

Now lets see an more complex example:

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315916/how-to-solve-compiling-error
\documentclass{modernCV} % <============================================

\moderncvstyle{mycasual} % <============================================
\moderncvcolor{blue}


\name{Joe}{Doe} 

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\chapter{nonsens} % <===================================================
\section{Languages} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}

\section{Languages 2} 
\mycvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\mycvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right} 
\mycvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}

\section{Languages 3} 
\mybcvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}{5cm}
\mybcvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right}{5cm} 
\mybcvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}{5cm}
\end{document}
```

I marked the three errors with `<===========`.  You will get an message that there are 3 errors and zero written pages (off course, document class is wrong!).

In the case of more than one error check always the `log` file and locate the **first** error! Why the first?  Because often the second, third etc error are only errors caused by the first one.

So locate your errors in general by

1. locating the **first** error in the log file.
2. correct this error
3. recompile and start with point 1. ...

Okay, our 1. error in the log file is a warning we should read and correct:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.24)  23 JUN 2016 01:34
entering extended mode
**./315916-Sample1.tex
(315916-Sample1.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\modernCV.cls"

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `modernCV',
               but the document class provides `moderncv'.
```

We have an typo in our used document class. Correct it to `moderncv` (no capital CV)!

The first error we have is:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `moderncvstylemycasual.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Here you need to know that `moderncv` builds some used file names by concatenating two parts, here `moderncvstyle` and `mycasual`.  Because we have **not** defined `mycasual` we got the error message that the resulting file could not be found.  Change `mycasual` to `casual` and this error is gone.

The second error is:

```
Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

That is caused by the error before and will be gone after correcting the first error and recompiling!

The following is caused by the error before, and is gone after correcting the first error and an recompile:

```
l.5 \moderncvcolor
                  {blue}

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

The 3. Error is that no pdf output is produced ...

So you see three errors, please correct the first both lines in my given second MWE and compile again three times.

Now we get 6 errors, because now `pdflatex` recognised an undefinded command `mycvitemwithcomment` and `mybcvitemwithcomment`.  Let's say that is a typo and change all 3 wrong `mycvitemwithcomment` to `cvitemwithcomment`.  Delete/comment the part for "Language 3".

Corrected MWE:

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315916/how-to-solve-compiling-error
\documentclass{moderncv} % <============================================ modernCV

\moderncvstyle{casual} % <============================================ mycasual
\moderncvcolor{blue}


\name{Joe}{Doe} 

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\chapter{nonsens} % <===================================================
\section{Languages} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}

\section{Languages 2} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language1}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language2}{Some text}{This text is located on the right} 
\cvitemwithcomment{Language3}{Some longer text}{This text is located on the right and it is longer}

\end{document}
```

Now have a look at the pdf.

[image: result corrected mwe]

There you will see an printed `nonsens` comming from the line `\chapter{nonsense}`. You see that **not** all errors must be found by LaTeX ...

Comment: Maybe add that in case of multiple errors, one best starts at the first, as the others might be consequential errors and are 1) in many cases not easy to understand and 2) might very well resolve them self once the first error is fixed. [As many editors by default show the bottom of the error list, this might not be obvious for ever user]

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize you were still writing on the answer - which is really great! (and your English is certainly better than mine)